# PHP not taking txt file as input

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $re = "/([AG][AT]AGAGG[TC]GC[GA])[ATGC]+(((AA|[AG])GTA))[ATGC][ATGC]+([AG]A[AG][GA]GG)[ATGC]+(GCCGA[GA][AG])[ATGC]+([TC][TC]GG)[ATGC]+([AG][CT]TG[TC]C[GA][TC])[ATGC]+([GA][CT][CG]G[AG]G[ATGC]G[TC]T[AT][CT])/"; 
$str = "np.txt";

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

This is my code when I am giving `$str` within the code. It works but when I am giving text file from directory it gives `Array()` only

```
np.txt ="AGAATGATAATTATCCTGAAAATATATTTTATATATTAACGGAATAATTATTTAAGGTAA
AGTAAGCGAGTCATTATTTTTTAATTTTATGAAATGGAATAATTTATTATTCGTCTGGTT
ATTCGCGAAATGTTAATAAAAATATAGCGTTTAGCTATTGGCAATCGAGGCAGATTAAGG
TAATCTTACAAAGTCCTACAAATCGTAGAGGTGCAAATCCGATAAGTACTTTTTCTGAGT
GGAGAACGAGGAGGAAAAAGGAAAGGCGTATTTGCCGAAATCAGTTAAGCGTCATCTTAA
TTGGTTGGGGTCGTTACCGAAAGGGACGACACTGTCGTAATCCTTGTATTACGGAGTGCT
ACTGCTAGGGTCGGTTCTATTCTTATTATTTCAGATTGCCTACCTCATCTTATGCGTTGC
ATAAATTCTCTCAGTAGATCCTCTTCTTTGTTTGGCTAGTATTTCATTACAAAGTAACTT
TTTTTAGAGGTTTTATGAATTTAATTGATTATTCAAGTTCGTTGCTGTCGATTATGCCGG
CATCGCTTGCTTTACTATTGGCTATGGTTACTCGACGAGTACTGCTGTCTTTAAGTGTCG
GCATCTTAGTCGGTGCCTTTATGCTTTCGGCAACATTTGCGGACGGTTTCGTTTATTTAA
AAAATATTGCTATCGGTTTGGTTTATGCTGACGGTGAATATTCGTTCGGAAAAGTACAGA
TCTTAATTTTCTTACTTTTATTAGGCGTATTTACCTCTTTATTAACTTATTCGGGCAGTA
ATCAGGCTTTTGCCAATTGGGCGAAGAAACATATTAAAGGGCGCCGCGGTGCGAAATTAT
TAACCGCCTGTTTAGTTTTCGTGACGTTTATCGACGACTATTTCCATAGTCTGGCTGTTG
GGGCGATTGCTCGACCGGTAACGGATAAATTTAAAGTTTCGCGTGCAAAATTAGCTTATA
TTCTTGATTCGACCGCCGCACCGATGTGCGTGCTTATGCCGGTTTCCAGCTGGGGAGCTT
CAATTATCGCAACAATCGGCGGTTTATTGGCGACTTATAATATTACCGAATATACGGCGA
TCAGCGCATTCGCTTCAATGAGTTTGATGAACTACTATGCGTTATTTGCCTTAATTATGG
TGTTTATCGTAGCTTATTTCTCATTTGATATCGGTTCGATGAGTCGTTTTGAAAGAAAAG
CGTTGGCTTCGGAAACACATACGAATGAAGATGCGGATGTCGAATCCAAAGGTCGAGTAT"
```

Comment: How are you reading the file? Are you using the function file() or file_get_content() or what?

Comment: Can you please try to explain it a bit better .... more code or more description... please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not reading the file, you are just putting its name in a string variable and then matching against the name.

Read the file

```
<?php
    $re = "/([AG][AT]AGAGG[TC]GC[GA])[ATGC]+(((AA|[AG])GTA))[ATGC][ATGC]+([AG]A[AG][GA]GG)[ATGC]+(GCCGA[GA][AG])[ATGC]+([TC][TC]GG)[ATGC]+([AG][CT]TG[TC]C[GA][TC])[ATGC]+([GA][CT][CG]G[AG]G[ATGC]G[TC]T[AT][CT])/"; 

    $str = file_get_contents("np.txt");

    preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. actually i need output from np.txt file , the text block which matched to regular expression but this code gives output as pattern which matched

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand what you are asking, but I am fairly sure it would be classed as a different question. So you had better ask it as another question.

Answer (score 0):

you are not opening the file as $str you are only setting the variable to np.txt. Try changing it to:

```
$filehandle = fopen("np.txt", "r");
$str = fread($filehandle ,8192);
```